# Hiding dynamically updated blocks

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a dash app. Its essence is to make a request to the database every 30 seconds and update the page according to them. The data is divided into 11 blocks, some of which may be empty. If they are empty, then I don't show it completely.

Each block has a row with a title (1) and a table with rows (2) (screenshot).
[image: ![image|690x76](upload://xH9rZDx92iSjmd7H69cLYseyWVK.png)]

I need to add a button to the title bar that will hide the table (2). I did this via a button callback with indexes.

```
@callback(
    Output({"type": "dynamic-card", "index": MATCH}, "style"),
    Input({"type": "dynamic-button", "index": MATCH}, "n_clicks")
)
```

But due to the fact that every time new data can appear and new blocks can be created, I recreate the buttons. Therefore, their `n_clicks = 0` and hidden blocks are revealed again.

I tried writing the `n_clicks` of each button to a file and reading them before updating. But it turns out that hiding will be the same for all users, but I need it separately for each.

**My question is how to save `n_clicks` after updating?** (and for each user to remain hidden for the duration of their session).

My code (removed the import of all styles for convenience, the page looks like the screenshot):

```
from dash import dcc, html, Input, Output, callback, MATCH, ctx
from datetime import datetime
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

refreshing_data = [
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [[1, '16/09 12:00', 'name', 'https://google.com/', 'status', '1 day 1 h', '1 day 1 h']],
    [[1, '16/09 12:00', 'name', 'https://google.com/', 'status', '1 day 1 h', '1 day 1 h']],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [[1, '16/09 12:00', 'name', 'https://google.com/', 'status', '1 day 1 h', '1 day 1 h']],
    'Last refresh at 15:19'
]

switch_case = {
    0: 'H0',
    1: 'H1',
    2: 'H2',
    3: 'H3',
    4: 'H4',
    5: 'H5',
    6: 'H6',
    7: 'H7',
    8: 'H8',
    9: 'H9',
    10: 'H10'
}


def template_small_card(row):
    date_req = row[1]
    operation = row[2]
    link = row[3]
    status = row[4]
    card = html.Div([
        html.H6("Content is {}, {}, {}, {}".format(date_req, operation, link, status))
    ],
    )
    return card


def template_big_card(list_of_small_cards, big_name):
    n = big_name
    card = html.Div(
        [
            html.Div([
                # button to hide the block
                html.Div(
                    [
                        html.Button(children=[html.Img(src='assets/vector1.png')],
                                    n_clicks=0,
                                    id={"type": "dynamic-button", "index": n},
                                    ),
                    ],
                ),
                html.Div([
                    html.H4("{}".format(big_name), className="card-title", ),
                ], ),
            ],
            ),
            html.Hr(),
            # I plan to hide this block
            html.Div([
                *list_of_small_cards
            ],
                id={"type": "dynamic-card", "index": n}
            )
        ],
    )
    return dbc.Row(children=[card], className="g-0")


def generate_big_card(data, big_name):
    if not data:
        return []
    else:
        result = []
        for ind in data:
            small_card = template_small_card(ind)
            result.append(small_card)
        big_card = template_big_card(result, switch_case[big_name])
        return big_card


layout = html.Div([
    html.Div('Request queue'),
    html.H6(id='time_update_1_vert'),
    dcc.Interval(
        id='interval-component_vert',
        interval=30 / 60 * 60000,
        n_intervals=0
    ),
    dbc.Row(id='row-tables_vert')
],
)


@callback(
    Output('time_update_1_vert', 'children'),
    Output('row-tables_vert', 'children'),
    Input('interval-component_vert', 'n_intervals'),
)
def update_data(n_intervals):
    list_of_df = refreshing_data
    columns_for_row = []
    time_update = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    for i in range(0, 11):
        dbc_column = generate_big_card(list_of_df[i], i)
        if dbc_column:
            columns_for_row.append(dbc_column)
    return time_update, columns_for_row


@callback(
    Output({"type": "dynamic-card", "index": MATCH}, "style"),
    Input({"type": "dynamic-button", "index": MATCH}, "n_clicks")
)
def update_card(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks % 2 == 1:
        style1 = {'display': 'none'}
    else:
        style1 = {}
    return style1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general problem is to share data between the callbacks. Which is solved with [`dcc.Store`](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/store) components.

Card's current visibility may be stored there. Let's assume, that all cards are visible by default.

```py
session_cards_visibility = dbc.Container([
    dcc.Store(
        id={'type': 'session_card_visibility', 
            'index': switch_case[index]},
        data=True,  # True means visible
        storage_type='session') for index in range(len(switch_case))
    ])

# ...

# somewhere in the layout:
layout = [
    # ...
    session_cards_visibility,
    html.Div('Request queue'),
    html.H6(id='time_update_1_vert'),
    # ...
```

Counting button clicks doesn't seem to be a reliable thing. And show/hide logic is better represented by a toggle, that by a button. So in the sample buttons are replaced with [`dbc.Checklist`](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/input/) with the only option.

```py
# in template_big_card() instead of html.Button
dbc.Checklist(
    id={"type": "dynamic-button", "index": n},
    options=[{"label": f"Option {n}", "value": True}],
    value=[True] if visible else [],  # visible - see below
    inline=True,
    switch=True)
```

May show or hide the card based on the current toggle state, and also update the corresponding session storage.

```py
@app.callback(
    Output({'type': 'dynamic-card', 'index': MATCH}, 'hidden'),
    Output({'type': 'session_card_visibility', 'index': MATCH}, 'data'),
    Input({'type': 'dynamic-button', 'index': MATCH}, 'value'),
    prevent_initial_call=True)
def update_card(toggle_options):  # toggle_options - is a list
    
    show_card = bool(toggle_options)  # value is chosen [True] or not []
    return (
        not show_card,  # hidden=True must be similar to style={'display': 'none'}
        show_card  # save the value in the session store
    )
```

Finally, `update_data()` should get all the stored values and pass them as an argument to `generate_big_card()` and `template_big_card()`.

```py
@app.callback(
    Output('time_update_1_vert', 'children'),
    Output('row-tables_vert', 'children'),
    Input('interval-component_vert', 'n_intervals'),
    State({"type": "session_card_visibility", "index": ALL}, "data"))
def update_data(_, visibilities):
    # ...
    for i in range(0, 11):
        dbc_column = generate_big_card(list_of_df[i], i, visibilities[i])
    # ...


def generate_big_card(data, big_name, visible):
    # ...
    big_card = template_big_card(result, switch_case[big_name], visible)
    # ...


def template_big_card(list_of_small_cards, big_name, visible=True):
    # ... set the toggle state as was mentioned above

    html.Div([*list_of_small_cards],
        id={"type": "dynamic-card", "index": n},
        hidden=not visible  # hide the card if necessary
    )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really works the way I needed it to!
Do you know how to make an arrow button, like I had, but so that its values change between True and False?

Comment: Maybe, use a button for just triggering an event. Have a variable picture into button's children. Redefine `update_card` as transform: `Input(dynamic-button.value)`, `State(session_card_visibility.data)` -> `session_card_visibility.data`, `dynamic-card.hidden`, `dynamic-button.children`. Based on only the storage value, flip the visibility, put the corresponding picture and title to button's children output.